# Button not in line with input fields

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/p5thLuwo/

[image]
I can't get my submit button to line up with the input fields in my form

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" align="center">
    <form id="form" name="form" style="width:80%">

        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label for="ptxt">Name:</label> 
            <input id="ptxt" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="ptxt[]" placeholder="Part" class="form-control"/>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="qtxt">Qty:</label> 
            <input id="qtxt" type="number" name="qtxt[]" placeholder="Quantity" value="1" min="0.5" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="ctxt">Cost per Item:</label>
            <input id="ctxt" type="text" name="ctxt[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>

            <button name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>

    </form>
</div>
```

If I add a label and the same properties as the input fields then it is positioned correctly but too big and also I do not want/need a label

[image]

```
<div class="row" align="center">
<form id="form" name="form" style="width:80%">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="ptxt">Name:</label> 
        <input id="ptxt" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="ptxt[]" placeholder="Part" class="form-control"/>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
        <label for="qtxt">Qty:</label> 
        <input id="qtxt" type="number" name="qtxt[]" placeholder="Quantity" value="1" min="0.5" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
        <label for="ctxt">Cost per Item:</label>
        <input id="ctxt" type="text" name="ctxt[]" class="form-control"  />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
        <label for="submit">.</label>
        <button name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-success form-control"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>

</form>
 </div>
```

So to summarize I'm trying to get the button to look like the first image but with the alignment in the second image.

Comment: add jsfiddle of your code, it will be more good

Comment: Your CSS seems to be important to include for an answer.

Comment: Just looking at the element classes, are you using bootstrap? That would be important information as well.

Comment: yeah, using bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dummy css class (abc in this case)

```
<div class="row" align="center">
    <form id="form" name="form" style="width:80%">

        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label for="ptxt">Name:</label> 
            <input id="ptxt" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="ptxt[]" placeholder="Part" class="form-control"/>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="qtxt">Qty:</label> 
            <input id="qtxt" type="number" name="qtxt[]" placeholder="Quantity" value="1" min="0.5" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="ctxt">Cost per Item:</label>
            <input id="ctxt" type="text" name="ctxt[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6 abc">
           <button name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
```

and give it Margin top as 3%

```
.abc {
    margin-top: 3%;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jk5hksue/

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 extra bootstrap columns:

```
<div class="row" align="center">
<form id="form" name="form" style="width:80%">
    <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label for="ptxt">Name:</label>
            <input id="ptxt" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="ptxt[]" placeholder="Part" class="form-control"/>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="qtxt">Qty:</label>
            <input id="qtxt" type="number" name="qtxt[]" placeholder="Quantity" value="1" min="0.5" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="ctxt">Cost per Item:</label>
            <input id="ctxt" type="text" name="ctxt[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: button still not in line

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it well. add an extra padding top like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ykv0me2z/